# Google sheet query where clause only return in one row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, where-clause

I usually use this formula but I do not know why this time it only show in one row. this formula just to call return to the other sheet.
Here is the formula :

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1sxvtnHEFvvs_BBoHN4uZu2yxGJpXhJXLuNdX1aidqQ4","Termination Report Sorted!C75:N200"),"SELECT Col5, Col12")`

and the result looks like this :

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlAm3.png)
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yELx.png)

its only filling the first row of the formula, which should have filled the column to the bottom
the result should look like this

> [Blockquote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNQ6n.png)

I already used this formula before and its working just fine, but today when I reopen the sheet it shows just like above.

Please help me to find the error or mistake in formula .

Comment: What debugging have you already done? What data exists in the source sheet/range? What data does the `IMPORTRANGE` formula return? What is the value in cell C72? Based on the foregoing, what result do you expect the formula to return?

Comment: It should return the data, filling the column, not just a row.
I already add additional information to the post

Comment: Please bear in mind that users don't have your spreadsheets, can't work on your data, and can't reproduce your problem. Also, you have reported the outcome of the problem, but provided no debugging information. Perhaps users are unable to resolve this and this is a "Google" problem. But _if_ we are to assist, we need to understand some basic debug info: such as, what/how much data was in the source sheet, whether the `IMPORTRANGE` formula was working, whether the `QUERY` was working at all or just returning a fraction of the data, whether the `select` clause might be the problem, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

*Try something like this:*

```js
=query(A1:B3,"select *",0)
```

- *set the third parameter `[headers]` to `0` to tell query there's no headers in that range; set as `1` to attribute first row as headers*
- as per [query documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343): *If omitted or set to -1, the value
  is guessed based on the content of data & sometimes results in the data coalesce(as happening in your scenario)*